# Magnets are bad for your computer; What about amps? Speakers?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, magnet

I have a Kenwood KA-4006 Amp that I have connected to my MacBook.

[image]

I know that speakers have magnets in them.  I just wanted to verify that there are no magnets in the amp that will mess with my Mac.  Do I need to worry about my computer getting too close to the speakers?

Comment: I have often wondered this myself. I keep a fairly powerful sub within about 4' of my computer, and haven't noticed any side effects. I don't know how close I can get it, and am certainly not risking it.

Comment: Way back in the era of floppy disks, speakers were often the culprit in "I lost my homework" stories -- as in "I spent 8 hours working on my paper in the computer lab, saved my paper, returned to my dorm room exhausted. I threw the floppy on top of my speakers and cranked up the music to clear my mind"

Comment: @Doug - interesting. Never lost one disc in that way, myself. Not even the oldest ones (the big ones, paper size).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most speakers are shielded, as are amps.

The only issue (considering the prevalence of non-CRT monitors) would be the hard drive, which is pretty well protected anyways.

In short **I wouldn't worry about it**.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my laptop half the time on top of two big Wharfendale speakers. In the last ten years nothing happened.

Yes, speakers are bad - in theory many things could happen. In practice computers as a whole, nowadays are not so sensitive, nor the parts in them.

So, go by the principle: "Did something happen so far ?" ... "No?" ... "Good, then probably I have nothing to worry about!" :-)